# How to direct the "return" key to click a specific submit button in html 5 form where there are multiple submit button?

Tags: html

I have a page with two separate forms "FormA" and "FormB". Each form has two different submit buttons. When the user finishes completing "FormA" and hits "Enter" button, I want "SubmitButtonA1" to be clicked not "SubmitButtonA2".

When the user finishes completing "FormB" and hits "Enter" button, I want "SubmitButtonB1" to be clicked not "SubmitButtonB2".

```
<form name="FormA">
<input type="text" value="" name="title">
...
<button type="submit" name="SubmitButtonA1" formaction="/LoadA" formmethod="get">Load</button>
<button type="submit" name="SubmitButtonA2" formaction="/UpdateA" formmethod="post">Update</button>

</form>

<form name="FormB">
<input type="text" value="" name="title">
...
<button type="submit" name="SubmitButtonB1" formaction="/LoadB" formmethod="get">Load</button>
<button type="submit" name="SubmitButtonB2" formaction="/UpdateB" formmethod="post">Update</button>

</form>
```

By default, it seems that html5 targets the first submit button in the form when the user clicks on the "Enter" button on their keyboard. How can I target the button I want instead of the first button?

Comment: There is a workaround. You can create a hidden button, with the same properties as the submit button, and position it first in order. Read [here](https://adamsilver.io/articles/forms-with-multiple-submit-buttons-are-problematic/) about it.